# C++ bitwise left shift by 32

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bitwise-operators

Currently I'm working on a brute force algorithm for the knapsack problem. Everything is working perfectly for small problem instances, for example 15 items. But when I run my program for bigger instances like 31 or 32, the algorithm is failing. I've run into a problem with bit-wise shift which I'm using to compute the number of possible solutions. For example with 10 items the program should make 2^10 iterations, so I'm using this statement:

```
unsigned long long int setCnt = (1 << 10);
```

The computed value 1024 is correct. But for `(1 << 31)` the computed value is 18446744071562067968 (max `unsigned long long int`), but should be 2147483648. `(1 << 32)` returns 0. It's like everything works just fine for shifting from 0 to 30 bits.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and compile my solution in x64 mode.
What causes this behaviour? How can I circumvent this?

Comment: How do you know the resulting values?

Comment: max unsigned long long is generally 2\*\*64-1 (18446744073709551615).  18446744071562067968 is 2\*\*64 - 2\*\*31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `1` is a `signed int` constant literal -- so the shift is done as a `signed int` shift (which is apparently just 32 bits including the sign on your compiler), so it overflows, leading to undefined behavior.

Try using `1ULL << 32` (or whatever other shift amount you want) -- the `ULL` suffix makes the constant an `unsigned long long`, matching the type of your desired result.  This might still overflow if the shift amount becomes too large for an `unsigned long long`, but until then it will work.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I did not realize that 1 is taken as signed int in this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Integer literals with no suffix that can fit in a signed int are taken as a signed int in **ALL** cases in C and C++