# C code not output the right number for long long int

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the size limits of `long long int` with the following code:

```
int main()
{
    long long int from, to;
    printf("signed long long int: ");
    bytes=sizeof(long long int);
    bits = 8* bytes;
    from = -(1 << (bits-1));
    to =  (1 << (bits-1)) - 1;
    printf(" %d bytes from %lld to %lld\n", bytes, from, to);
}
```

the output is:

```
signed long long int:  8 bytes from -2147483648 to 2147483647
```

I expect it to be -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: that code does not compile....

Comment: Assigning the result of a calculation to a variable of type `long long int` will not result in the calculation being performed as `long long int`. Only the result will be converted. This is similar to how `double x = 1/2;` is `0` and not `0.5`. You should cast the operands to make sure the calculation is performed with the precision you want.

Comment: so many duplicates: [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714), [left shift on 64 bits fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048047/995714), [Compute signed long max value in C using bit shift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41418472/995714), [How do I bit shift a long by more than 32 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2404439/995714), [bitwise left shift by 32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40951434/995714), [Why doesn't left bit shift << shift beyond 31 for long int datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24117934/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Shifting more than 32 bits of a uint64\_t integer on an x86 machine Undefined Behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499104/is-shifting-more-than-32-bits-of-a-uint64-t-integer-on-an-x86-machine-undefined)

Answer (score 3):

> What's wrong with the code above?

`1 << (bits-1)` is shifting the *integer constant* of type  `int` outside its range and leads to integer overflow and *undefined behavior*.

You may want to consider shifting a `long long` rather than an `int`.

```
1LL << (bits-1)
```

Yet this too is integer overflow and *undefined behavior* as it shifts the 1 outside the `long long` range.

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; ... If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.  C11dr §6.5.7 4

---

To portable find the range of `long long`, use `LLONG_MIN,  LLONG_MAX` from `<limit.h>`.

```
#include <limit.h>

printf("%d bytes from %lld to %lld\n", bytes, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
```

---

**If** `long long` lacks padding,  (something very very common, by not required by C), the below will print the max value of `long long`.

```
#include <limit.h>
int main(void) {
  long long max;
  int bytes = sizeof(long long);
  int bits = CHAR_BIT * bytes;
  long long max_halfish = 1LL << (bits-2);
  long long max = (max_halfish - 1) + max_halfish;
  printf("max %lld\n", max);
}
```

`min` is simply `(-max - 1)` **if** we assume the very common 2's complement coding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to coerce the `1` before shifting, otherwise is it treated as an `int` constant:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int from, to;
    printf("signed long long int: ");

    int bytes = sizeof(long long int);
    int bits = 8 * bytes;

    from = -(((long long)1) << (bits-1));
    to =  (((long long)1) << (bits-1)) - 1;

    printf(" %d bytes from %lld to %lld\n", bytes, from, to);
}
```

Or use the more readable `1LL` as @phuclv pointed out.

Output:

```
signed long long int:  8 bytes from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

`1` is an int literal, therefore `1 << (bits-1)` is done in `int` type, which invokes undefined behavior since you're shifting more than the type's width. Use `1LL` instead for a `long long` value

Answer (score 0):

1 is an integer constant, change to 1LL to get the result in long long int.

```
int main() {

  long long int from, to;
  int bytes,bits;

  printf("signed long long int: ");
  bytes=sizeof(long long int);
  bits = 8* bytes;
  from = -(1LL << (bits-1));
  to =  (1LL << (bits-1)) - 1;
  printf(" %d bytes from %lld to %lld\n", bytes, from, to);
}
```